# Locating Native Android Dialog Button in Appium

Tags: android, appium

### The Problem

I am automating Android hybrid app (Cordova) UI tests using Appium. I have encountered the following problem - one of the pages in my app is in immersive mode causing Android to bring up the following dialog - [image: Native Android top up]
I am attempting to click OK but not having much luck due to the inability to locate the button element.

### Things I have tried

I have tried using uiautomatorviewer to generate xpath for selecting the button. Unfortunately, uiautomatorviewer does not see this button. It only offers information about the application's webview.

I have tried finding all elements on the page by running

`driver.find_elements(MobileBy.XPATH, "//*")`

in 'NATIVE_APP' context. This only seems to return WebElements failing to locate the native OK button.

BitBar seems to suggest using image recognition(?!) to solve this problem in this article - http://bitbar.com/how-to-use-image-recognition-for-mobile-app-and-game-testing/. Surely there is an easier way?

### Information About the Setup

Appium - 1.6.3

Android - 4.4 (API level 19)

### Existing Posts

I was able to find a post on the Appium forums about the exact same issue - https://discuss.appium.io/t/android-with-full-screen-mode/2621. It appears that nobody has answered the question, though.